# CTE with bidirectional entries

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

I want to walk a directed graph. I need all involved nodes.

I want to support both cases (result should be always 1,2,3):

```
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1,2),(2,3);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1,2),(3,2);
```

```
WITH RECURSIVE traverse(id, path, cycle) AS (
    SELECT a, ARRAY[a], false
    FROM foo WHERE a = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT GREATEST(a,b), traverse.path || GREATEST(a,b), GREATEST(a,b) = ANY(traverse.path)
    FROM traverse
    INNER JOIN foo
    ON LEAST(a,b) = traverse.id
    WHERE NOT cycle   
  )
SELECT * FROM traverse
```

Table foo can have up to 50 Mio records. Index is on both column (not multicolumn index). It doesnt work very "fast" - without GREATEST and LEAST its very fast. Any other solutions?

**Update**: An iterative solution is not that bad after analyzing requirements again:

- There are 54 Mio edges and 21 Mio nodes in the db - there are distinct graphs in the db each connected graph has 3 to 100 nodes
- it worked well with the question "give me all related nodes" --> 20msec (graph depth = 13)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS edges, nodes;

CREATE TABLE nodes
(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE edges
(
  "from" INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES nodes(id),
  "to" INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES nodes(id)
);

INSERT INTO nodes SELECT generate_series(1,5);
INSERT INTO edges VALUES
-- circle
(1,2),(2,3),(3,1),
-- other direction
(4,3);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION walk_graph(param_node_id INTEGER)
  RETURNS TABLE (id INTEGER)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
  var_node_ids INTEGER[] := ARRAY[param_node_id];
  var_iteration_node_ids INTEGER[] := ARRAY[param_node_id];
BEGIN

  WHILE array_length(var_iteration_node_ids, 1) > 0 LOOP  
      
    var_iteration_node_ids := ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT "to" FROM edges
      WHERE "from" = ANY(var_iteration_node_ids)
      AND NOT("to" = ANY(var_node_ids))
      UNION
      SELECT DISTINCT "from" FROM edges
      WHERE "to" = ANY(var_iteration_node_ids)
      AND NOT("from" = ANY(var_node_ids)));     
   
    var_node_ids := var_node_ids || var_iteration_node_ids;
  END LOOP;

  RETURN QUERY SELECT unnest(var_node_ids);
END $$;

SELECT * FROM walk_graph(2);
```

Comment: You could create virtual columns on the table and index them. You can also create indexes on materialised view, which would avoid modifying the table.

Comment: With the iterative method i was able to do it in 25msec --> just make a UNION and make the SELECT in the opposite direction. For my requirement (lots of distinct graphs with up to 100 nodes) its works more than well ;-)